# Unsupported operand type of an string index

Tags: python, python-3.x

I tried to run the code down below, but I couldn't because it launched the following error:

> unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'int'.

I've been searching and I found that it has something to do with the input, but not in this case.

```
st = "text"
for i in range(0, n):
    for j in st:
        if j == 0:
            st[j] = st[len(st)]
        else:
            st[j] = st[j - 1]
```

Comment: What is the code *meant* to do?

Comment: `1` is an `int` and `j` is a `str`. The `-` operator does not work between `str` and `int` objects. Furthermore, you cannot mutate a string, so things like `st[0] = 'x'` will not work *anyway* even if the expression `j - 1` evaluated to an `int`. IOW, you have a lot of problems in this piece of code.

Comment: Post the full traceback.

Comment: So note, `j` will **never** equal `0`.

Answer (score 3):

The problematic part is `st[j] = st[j - 1]`, more specifically `j - 1` where you are subtracting 'str' and 'int' types. This is not supported in Python.

Comment: Ok, I already know that, what I try to do is to change the index of the character to a new one.

Comment: It really depends what you are trying to solve here. If you want `j` to be integer depending on `st` you could write: `for j, chr in enumerate(st)`. `j` would be now index ranging from 0..3 and `chr` would be individual characters of your string. Read more about [enumerate](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate)

Answer (score 0):

The first problem you are encountering is that `j` is a string and you cannot substract an integer from a string.

```
j = 't'
j - 1 # TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'int'
```

The next problem you will encounter is that strings are immutable so you cannot set a given character of a string.

```
st = 'test'
st[0] = 'a' # TypeError: 'str' object does not support item assignment
```

Since a string is immutable, you will need to create a new one if you want to change even one character. In that case, it seems what you want to do is rotate your string by `n`. This can be achieved like this.

```
def rotate(s, n):
    if s:
        n = n % len(s)
        return s[-n:] + s[:-n] # This creates a new string
    else:
        return ''

rotate('test', 1) # 'ttes'
```

Answer (score 0):

You have several errors. Here is a code which I believe does what you want:

```
n = 1
st = "text"
# Make a copy of st, but make it a list
st_new = list(st)
for i in range(0, n):
    # Loop over characters c and their indices j in st
    for j, c in enumerate(st):
        # Assign to st_new, lookup values in st
        if j == 0:
            st_new[j] = st[len(st) - 1]  # The last index is len(st) - 1
        else:
            st_new[j] = st[j - 1]
# Convert st_new to a str
st_new = ''.join(st_new)
```

The comments should explain the changes. Main points:

- You cannot assign to a `str` (the `st` variable), because `str`s are immutable. Use `list`s instead, with each element being a single character (`str` of length 1).
- When you loop over a `str`, what you get are its characters, not the indices `j` you are looking for. I've used `enumerate()` which gives you both characters and indices.
- The last index in `st` is not `len(st)`, but `len(st) - 1`, because Python's indexing is 0-based. Also, because Python supports negative periodic indexing, your whole if statement is not actually needed. Try leaving it out.